# sql timediff function

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

What is the proper way to use mysql TIMEDIFF, (or something similar)? In database I have a column called date, and it is setup  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I'm trying to calculate the differene between the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and right now in a row, and than echo that to all the rows.. here's my script

```
  <?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
  mysql_select_db("beyondmotors");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM currentrentals");

  echo "<table border='2'>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Year</th>
  <th>Make</th>
  <th>Model</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Insurance</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Notes</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['insurance'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
      echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be heavily dependent on your output.

For example, `TIMEDIFF()` outputs is hours, minutes, seconds. As such, it is limited to the data type `TIME`.

Given a unit of `SECOND`, `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is a more robust solution.

All of this is well documented in [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

In the end, you typically see these calculations done with code. That is not with SQL. In your case PHP. You could do simple arithmetic by subtracting the timestamps from `strtotime()`. Or if you are using PHP >= 5.3, you could use [`DateTime::diff`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

As an aside, avoid naming your columns keywords, i.e. `date`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
SELECT (fields), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date FROM currentrentals
```

And then you can access date with `$row['date']`. Now you can easily subtract these dates.

```
$timesince = date(format, time() - $row['date']);
```

Hope that helps.